# My android service Mqtt client app keeps crashing

Tags: android-service, mqtt, crash

Good day, i really need help because this is now a big headache. the code looks fine but when i click on the subscribe button, the app will crash.

this is my android manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.generalsteinacoz.realmqttclient" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

</uses-permission>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service  android:name=".MQTTService"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

this is the code for the main Activity (i.e UI)

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.example.generalsteinacoz.realmqttclient.MQTTService;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

EditText edt_host, edt_port, editTopicSub;
TextView txt_message;
Button btnSub;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    edt_host = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_host);
    edt_port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_port);
    editTopicSub = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_sub);
  btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave_sub);
    txt_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_messageBody);
  onClick_Btn_Sub();
  }

  public void getMessage(String mess){
    txt_message.setText(mess);
  }

  public String setTopic(){
    String mainTopic = editTopicSub.getText().toString();
    return mainTopic;
 }

 public String setbrokerPort(){
    String mainBrokerPort = edt_host.getText()+":"+            edt_port.getText().toString();
 return mainBrokerPort;
 }

  public void onClick_Btn_Sub(){
    btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startService(new Intent("MQTTService"));
        }
     });
   }

 @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_first, menu);
    return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

this is the code for the service class

```java
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttAsyncClient;
  import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
  import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
  import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient;
  import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
  import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
  import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
  import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
  import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttSecurityException;
   import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

  import com.example.generalsteinacoz.realmqttclient.FirstActivity;

 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.Service;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentFilter;
 import android.content.res.Configuration;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
  import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
 import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
 import android.os.Binder;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.os.IBinder;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Toast;


 public class MQTTService extends Service {
  FirstActivity fa = new FirstActivity();

 private static final String TAG = "MQTTService";
  private static boolean hasWifi = false;
  private static boolean hasMmobile = false;
  private Thread thread;
   private ConnectivityManager mConnMan;
   private volatile IMqttAsyncClient mqttClient;
   private String deviceId;

  class MQTTBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        IMqttToken token;
        boolean hasConnectivity = false;
        boolean hasChanged = false;
        NetworkInfo infos[] = mConnMan.getAllNetworkInfo();

        for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++){
            if (infos[i].getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")){
                if((infos[i].isConnected() != hasMmobile)){
                    hasChanged = true;
                    hasMmobile = infos[i].isConnected();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, infos[i].getTypeName() + " is " +          infos[i].isConnected());
            } else if ( infos[i].getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") ){
                if((infos[i].isConnected() != hasWifi)){
                    hasChanged = true;
                    hasWifi = infos[i].isConnected();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, infos[i].getTypeName() + " is " +    infos[i].isConnected());
            }
        }

        hasConnectivity = hasMmobile || hasWifi;
        Log.v(TAG, "hasConn: " + hasConnectivity + " hasChange: " +     hasChanged + " - "+(mqttClient == null || !mqttClient.isConnected()));
        if (hasConnectivity && hasChanged && (mqttClient == null ||   !mqttClient.isConnected())) {
            doConnect();
        } else if (!hasConnectivity && mqttClient != null &&   mqttClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doDisconnect()");
            try {
                token = mqttClient.disconnect();
                token.waitForCompletion(1000);
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
     };

   public class MQTTBinder extends Binder {
     public MQTTService getService(){
        return MQTTService.this;
     }
   } 

  @Override
   public void onCreate() {
    IntentFilter intentf = new IntentFilter();
    setClientID();
    intentf.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(new MQTTBroadcastReceiver(), new      IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
     mConnMan = (ConnectivityManager)        getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  }

 @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged()");
      android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  }

   private void setClientID(){
      WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)       getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
       deviceId = wInfo.getMacAddress();
      if(deviceId == null){
          deviceId = MqttAsyncClient.generateClientId();
      }
   }

   private void doConnect(){
      Log.d(TAG, "doConnect()");
      IMqttToken token;
       MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
      options.setCleanSession(true);
       try {
         // mqttClient = new MqttAsyncClient(fa.setbrokerPort(), deviceId,   new MemoryPersistence());
         mqttClient = new MqttAsyncClient("tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883",   deviceId, new MemoryPersistence());
         token = mqttClient.connect();
         token.waitForCompletion(3500);
         mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttEventCallback());
         token = mqttClient.subscribe("#", 0);
         //token = mqttClient.subscribe(fa.setTopic(), 0);
         token.waitForCompletion(5000);
      } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (MqttException e) {
        switch (e.getReasonCode()) {
            case MqttException.REASON_CODE_BROKER_UNAVAILABLE:
            case MqttException.REASON_CODE_CLIENT_TIMEOUT:
            case MqttException.REASON_CODE_CONNECTION_LOST:
            case MqttException.REASON_CODE_SERVER_CONNECT_ERROR:
                Log.v(TAG, "c" +e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            case MqttException.REASON_CODE_FAILED_AUTHENTICATION:
                Intent i = new Intent("RAISEALLARM");
                i.putExtra("ALLARM", e);
                Log.e(TAG, "b"+ e.getMessage());
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "a" + e.getMessage());
        }
     }
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
      return START_STICKY;
   }

   private class MqttEventCallback implements MqttCallback {

     @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {


     }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {

     }

     @Override
     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
      public void messageArrived(String topic, final MqttMessage msg) throws    Exception {
         Log.i(TAG, "Message arrived from topic" + topic);
         Handler h = new Handler(getMainLooper());
         h.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent launchA = new Intent(MQTTService.this,   FirstActivity.class);
                 launchA.putExtra("message", msg.getPayload());
                //TODO write somethinkg that has some sense
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                       launchA.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_F RONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                 } /*else {
                    launchA.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                }*/
                startActivity(launchA);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MQTT Message:\n" +   new String(msg.getPayload()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    fa.getMessage(msg.getPayload().toString());
             }
          });
      }
   }

  public String getThread(){
    return Long.valueOf(thread.getId()).toString();
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onBind called");
    return null;
   }

   }
```

Comment: What is the error/stack trace from the crash?

Comment: unfortunately, Real Mqtt Client has stopped.

Comment: There will be a lot more info in the logcat output. We need to see this to work out why it's failing. Please update the question with the relevant bit of the logcat output